# Insert data on merge cells in ms word using python

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

I have a table wherein I have merge cells in it, the problem now is I'm having problems accessing those merge cells so I can't input any data.

Here is the code for my table:

```
import docx

document = docx.Document()

table = document.add_table(rows=5, cols=4, style='Table Grid')
a = table.cell(0,0)
b = table.cell(2,2)
A = a.merge(b)

c = table.cell(0,3)
d = table.cell(1,3)
B = c.merge(d)

e = table.cell(3,0)
f = table.cell(4,0)
C = e.merge(f)

g = table.cell(3,1)
h = table.cell(4,3)
D = g.merge(h)

document.save('table.docx')
```

So far, the table in 'table.docx' looks like this:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKMqK.png)

Can anyone help me how to input data on those merged cells?

Comment: You need to understand non uniform tables in word.  Investigate if you can use the cells(x) method rather then the cell(i,j) method.  The cell method takes a single index and counts cells from top left to bottom right.  It is not affected by merged cells unlike the cell(i,j) method.

Comment: Where is the problem? I don't see any code that attempts to access the merged cell. Also, what is the (complete) error traceback? How do you know it's not working? These are things we need to know to help you.

Comment: It's working now, this site (https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/216) helped me solve it. The site is not really talking about merge cells but I kinda get an idea with it. And it seems like I'm accessing the merge cells the wrong way before.

Comment: I've marked this question for closing as "not reproducible" since not details of *how* it was solved have been put *in an **answer***. You might want to take a moment to write up an answer, which would certainly be useful to other site users over the years...